# python plotnine: color brewer not enough

Tags: python, ggplot2, visualization, data-manipulation, plotnine

I am using python version of ggplot with the following code and have the image attached but the colors are not enough for coloring all the categories. I am wondering what the ways are to get a palettes with more colors but still retain the relation that lower number has a lighter color while higher number gets a darker one.

```
pretty = p9.ggplot(data=s2_test3, mapping = p9.aes(x='index', y='value', colour = "equity_as_number"))+ p9.geom_point(alpha = 0.02)
pretty = pretty + p9.facet_grid("gender~outcome")
pretty + p9.geom_smooth(method = 'loess') + p9.scale_color_brewer(type ='seq')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using plotnine, you can specify scales manually so that you can create whatever you wish.  I personally usually look to matplotlib's gradients (using `cmap`) before trying to manually create my own (using `gradient*`).

Here are some example scales, you can tweak them to your liking.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": range(100), "y": [0]*100, color="x"})

plt = p9.ggplot(p9.aes(x="x", y="y", fill="x"), df) + p9.geom_tile() + p9.themes.theme_void()
```

The `scale_fill_gradient*` class of functions allows you to specify your own arbitrary gradient. If you're really picky, you can spend your time with these functions and get whatever color gradient you wish.

`plt1 = plt + p9.scale_fill_gradient(low="#FFFFFF", high="#000044", guide=False)`

[image]

The `scale_fill_cmap` class allows you to specify matplotlib's color gradients that can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

`plt2 = plt + p9.scale_fill_cmap(name="gist_ncar", guide=false)`

[image]

You can create a scale that slowly desaturates using `scale_fill_desaturate`

`plt3 = plt + p9.scale_fill_desaturate(color="blue", guide=False)`

[image]